# Floating for menu items is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm an amateur and I'm practicing. But when I code this I can't get the margin right for menu items.

This is my project:

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.top-f{
    font-size: .9rem;
}
.h1brand{
    color: #0c2e8a;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
}
.logo h1{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.nav-icon{
    margin: 0 0;
}
.logo span{
    color: #50d8af;
}
.logo:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu ul li a{
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    min-width: 15rem;
}
.dropdown-menu a:hover{
    background: #9fcdff;
}
.background-img{
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 65vh;
    max-height: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: .4;
    position: absolute;
}
.headcolor{
    color: #0c2e8a;
}
.headcolor2{
    color: #50d8af;
}
.btn{
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.mc{
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}
.navbar-toggler{
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!--  Meta  -->
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>My New Pen!</title>

<!--  Styles  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row border-bottom top-f">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--email and phonenumber-->
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 d-lg-inline d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none">
                        <ul class="list-inline mt-3 mb-3 text">
                            <li class="list-inline-item mr-3 border-right pr-3">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone text-secondary"></i>
                                <span class="ml-2 text-secondary">09905645285</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item mr-3">
                                <i class="fas fa-envelope text-secondary"></i>
                                <span class="ml-2 text-secondary">parsaking@example.com</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--social media-->
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-4  d-lg-inline d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none">
                        <ul class="list-inline mb-3 mt-3 text-secondary float-lg-right">
                            <li class="list-inline-item pl-2 pr-2 text-secondary">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary">
                                <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary">
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light  ">

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Brand -->
                    <a href="#" class="display-4 font-weight-bold logo  col-xl-6 col-lg-6 float-left">
                        <h1 class="h1brand ">Reve
                            <span>al</span>
                        </h1>
                    </a>

                    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon nav-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Navbar links -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-xl-6 col-lg-6 " id="collapsibleNavbar">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> HOME</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> TUTORIAL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> TUTORIAL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> DROPDOWN</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"> CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--start section offer-->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" class="background-img">
            <div class="col-12 mc mt-5">
                <h2 class="display-3 font-weight-bold headcolor">making
                    <span class="headcolor2">your ideas </span>
                    <br>happen</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mc mt-5">
                <button class=" btn btn-lg btn-primary">Get GetSarted</button>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary ml-4">Our Projects</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--scripts-->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you help me to make xl and lg float right and responsive, please?

I tried everything to solve this problem but I failed every time.

And it's reveral theme, made with bootstrap.

It wants more text from me and I'm not very good in English. Oh, how can I tell?

I don't know much about CSS and HTML and this is a disaster.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's hard to understand what is your need... Please, clarify your question explaining what is the desired result, not saying that you are not good or similar to that

Comment: i want my navbar float right.my Purpose is links in header.

Comment: Don't worry, this stuff takes some time to learn! Just don't give up easily. Have a look at [FreeCodeCamp](https://freecodecamp.org), it's a great place to learn HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and the likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your structure to make it aligned. As of now your navbar is aligned. Please confirm if it solves your problem.

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.top-f {
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.h1brand {
  color: #0c2e8a;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
}

.logo h1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.nav-icon {
  margin: 0 0;
}

.logo span {
  color: #50d8af;
}

.logo:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 15rem;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background: #9fcdff;
}

.background-img {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 65vh;
  max-height: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: .4;
  position: absolute;
}

.headcolor {
  color: #0c2e8a;
}

.headcolor2 {
  color: #50d8af;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.mc {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My New Pen!</title>

  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <body>



    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row border-bottom top-f">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <!--email and phonenumber-->
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 d-lg-inline d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none">
              <ul class="list-inline mt-3 mb-3 text">
                <li class="list-inline-item mr-3 border-right pr-3"><i class="fa fa-phone text-secondary"></i><span class="ml-2 text-secondary">09905645285</span></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item mr-3"><i class="fas fa-envelope text-secondary"></i><span class="ml-2 text-secondary">parsaking@example.com</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--social media-->
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-4  d-lg-inline d-md-inline d-sm-none d-none">
              <ul class="list-inline mb-3 mt-3 text-secondary float-lg-right">
                <li class="list-inline-item pl-2 pr-2 text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></li>
                <li class="list-inline-item  pl-2 pr-2 border-left text-secondary"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light  ">


        <!-- Brand -->
        <a href="#" class="display-4 font-weight-bold logo">
          <h1 class="h1brand ">Reve<span>al</span></h1>
        </a>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon nav-icon"></span>
                    </button>

        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="collapsibleNavbar" style="">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> HOME</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> TUTORIAL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> TUTORIAL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> DROPDOWN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"> CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!--start section offer-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" class="background-img">
        <div class="col-12 mc mt-5">
          <h2 class="display-3 font-weight-bold headcolor">making <span class="headcolor2">your ideas </span><br>happen</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mc mt-5">
          <button class=" btn btn-lg btn-primary">Get GetSarted</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary ml-4">Our Projects</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!--scripts-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Additionally, you are using mix of container-fluid and container in your code. Both have different purposes. So i suggest you to read the documentation of bootstrap before using them